# FHIR json schema

Tags: jsonschema, hl7-fhir

Is there a complete or partial JSON schema for HL7 FHIR resources?
I saw this. http://www.interopen.org/candidate-profiles/care-connect/CareConnect-AllergyIntolerance-1.html

But the JSON scchema is not available. [This is also not functioning.](https://github.com/BlackPearSw/fhir-schema-dstu2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON schemas will be published as a standard part of release 3.  You can find the current draft here: http://build.fhir.org/fhir.schema.json.zip

There's still a bit of fine-tuning to do.  Feedback welcome.

Comment: Am using this. For an simple input like this { "resourceType": "AllergyIntolerance", "identifier" : "01",   "patient" : { "reference" : "Patient/0002" } } , I get invalid json. Since the schema cannot resolve, DomainResource.schema.json#/definitions/DomainResource. Similarly for Reference.schema.json. Do I need to edit the id part of schema to point my local file? this one , "id": "http://hl7.org/fhir/json-schema/AllergyIntolerance"

Comment: I changed the "$ref" too, to point the local schema files. Now working for me. Thank you @Lloyd

Answer (score 1):

You may try this: https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger
and obtain the json schemas from swagger.json.

Answer (score 1):

You can run on your computer terminal:

```
sudo curl -i -H "Accept: [VER-HEAD]" https://your-fhir-base-url/metadata
```

- use "application/json+fhir" for DSTU2 compatible
- use "application/fhir+json" for  anything greater than STU2

And the response will return JSON data on your terminal