# JSON Schema for FHIR false positives

Tags: jsonschema, hl7-fhir

I am new to JSON Schema, and am trying to validate JSON based on the HL7-FHIR schemas. Data I think should be invalid (and that the official Java-based [validator](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/validator.zip) says are invalid) shows up as valid.

For example, `{"dog": "food"}` should be invalid, because when I run the validator, I get:

```
> java -jar org.hl7.fhir.validator.jar bad.json -defn definitions.json.zip
    .. load FHIR from definitions.json.zip
    .. connect to tx server @ http://tx.fhir.org/r3 
     (vnull-null)
    .. validate
*FAILURE* validating bad.json:  error:1 warn:0 info:0
Fatal @ $ (line 1, col2) : Unable to find resourceType property
```

But if I paste the `fhir.schema.json` file from [here](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/fhir.schema.json.zip) into a JSON Schema validator like the one [here](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/), and evaluate `{"dog": "food"}`, it's valid.

It's valid even if I supply a `resourceType`, which I thought might cause the restrictions to kick in. It's also valid if I copy an example I expect to be valid—say, this Practitioner [example](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/practitioner-example-f007-sh.json.html)—and change some of the types (set `name` to be a string rather than an array, for example).

I'm not sure if I'm running into a problem with the HL7-FHIR JSON Schema in particular or with JSON Schemas in general. I believe my question is different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427110/fhir-json-schema) one because it appears that we're up to release 3.0, and so the schema I'm using is updated.

Comment: I'm pretty new to JSON Schema myself but from the HL7 meeting that just happened in Madrid, I know that the schema is not that mature - so I'd err on the side that it's not right. I haven't looked into it yet properly though so that's just a guess!